# Spark column with white space DataFrame -> Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Before I start - I know column names with white spaces are inherintly bad. In my case it is imposed on us by a 3rd party commercial product.

I also understand I can escape column names using back ticks. Here is my use case:

```
    // Define a class
case class MyClass (
  field1: String,
  `my field 2`: String
)

    // Create a DataFrame
val myDf = Seq(
  ("value1", "value2"),
  ("value3", "value4")
).toDF("field1", "my field 2")

    // Inspect the schema, note the column name /w space
myDf.printSchema
root
 |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my field 2: string (nullable = true)

    // Convert into a Dataset
val myDs = myDf.as[MyClass]

Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
Message: cannot resolve '`my$u0020field$u00202`' given input columns: [field1, my field 2];
StackTrace:   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
```

Using the implicit conversion, it seems to use unicode to trap the white spaces and then fails to do the mapping.

Is there a solution / work around for this sort of thing ?

Comment: what is the spark version you are using ? it works in 2.3.0

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22442

Comment: Thanks everyone! I didnt find the original issue when I searched. This is a duplicate sorry.